# What does the word 'Asura' mean in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, asuras, vedic-gods, etymology

The Danavas and Daityas are referred to as Asuras in the Puranas but in The Vedas many Devas are also referred as Asuras.

> May the golden-handed, life-bestowing, well-guiding, exhilarating and affluent **Savitri [Asura]** be present;
> for the deity, if worshipped in 
> the evening, is at hand, driving away Rakshasas and Yatudhanas.(Rig Veda 1.135.10)

Even Devas like Indra, Agni, Varuna, Rudra (Shiva) are often called Asuras in the Vedas especially in Rig Veda.

So what does the word Asura mean in the Vedas?

Comment: Asura word has multiple meanings. Asura also means Powerful. Basically, Asura can be anyone who emerges from Prajapati/Brahma.

Comment: @OnkarKarambe Shatapata Brahmana says that Prajapati/Brahma in creation created two groups of  beings devas and asuras and valmiki Ramayana says devas drink sura so they are called suras while the asura does not drink sura  so they are called asuras.But there may be some diffearent meaning of asura IN Rig veda.It is possible that powerfully beings may have called asura.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda An  interesting question and challenging too. I will try to answer in detail soon. For time being I am quoting a couplet from RigVeda " mahat devanam asuratva ekam".

Comment: @B.N.Bhaskar ok waiting for it:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word Asura has  2 meanings in the text Rig Veda 
In positive sense and negative sense.

The word asa means breath and the word Asura would mean who has his strength in the breath or who is the possessed of breath (the meaning given by yaksha nirukta).That means an asura is someone who is posser of breath that he could perform Great actions by his power or a very powerful supreme Being.

> For they are **Asuras** of Gods, the friendly make, both of you, our lands exceeding fruitful.(Rig Veda 7.65.2)

Here Varuna Mirta as called asuras as they are very powerful beings and similiarly powerful  deities like Rudra(Shiva),Indra,Agni have been called asuras.

Asuras in negative sense is also discribed in vedas like yajur Veda tattireya samhita kanda 2 Prapathaka 4.3

> The **gods** and the **Asuras** were in conflict;

Gods means devas and yajurveda provides further detail of the fight between devas and asuras.also in Rigveda asuras have negative meaning like

> BRING song and hymn to Agni, **Asura-slayer, enlightener of all and thought**-bestower.(Rig Veda 7.13.1)

Here Agni deva has called the asuravan which means asura slayer

> This prelude of my speech I now will utter, whereby we Gods may quell our **Asura foemen.**(Rig Veda 10.53.4)

Here Agni deva says that may we defeat our foeman that is the asuras.

> Radiant, as high Truth, cherished, best at winning strength, Truth based upon the statute that supports the heavens,
>   He rose, a light, that kills Vṛtras **and enemies, best slayer of the Dasyus, Asuras, and foes.**

Here Surya deva has said to slay the Asuras.

Finally,the word 'Asura' in the Vedas means possessed of breath or  very powerfull beings and it also means the diffearent class of beings who quarell with the Devas as discribed in Brahmans and Puranas.

Answer (score 13):

[Yāska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C4%81ska) in 7th century BCE analysed/interpreted the Vedas. He is the first known grammarian which traced the meaning of Vedic words. He provided various meaning of Asura in his work [Nirukta](https://archive.org/details/nighantuniruktao00yaskuoft)

**1. *a-su-rata* > *a (na) su (susthu) ra (rata) sthanesu* 'not fixed at one place' or 'not very happy'**

**2. *as* *(√as 'to throw')* *-u-ra* 'thrown out or striped out from their place'**

**3. *asu + ra* 'possessed of breath'**

**4. *a (na) - su (good) -ra* 'born out of evil'**

**5. *(v)-asurtva > vasurtva* 'possessor of water/wealth'**

Outside samhita text Asura only has negative connotation.

Comment: That's Informative!

Comment: Btw see my answer the word Asura has two meanings in the vedas

Answer (score 4):

' mahat devanam asuratva ekam' is a couplet repeated at the end of every hymn of the verse RV.3.55.(1-22). The entire verse is devoted to Agni.At first I could not understand why Rishi is refering to Deva and Asur. Then the concept of poetic analysis came to my mind,according to which a poet wants to emphasise the main theme by repeating. And in this sense it becomes clear what Rishi wants to tell us - Agni is known as Deva by many names such as Apam Napat, Matrishwa, Vaishwanar etc, but as Asura he is only one i.e. Sun. Thus the meaning of Asura here is Sun. In the hymn RV.3.29(14) Agni is said to be born from the abdomen of Asura (yat Asurasya jattarat ajayat).

One more verse of Rig Veda RV.10.92.6 indicates that the term Asura mean 'Sun'-

*krAnA rudrA maruto vishva kristyo divah shyanAso asursya nilayah*

meaning-  RudrA Maruts speedly reach to the farmers of the world, as the eagles move in the blue sky of Asura i.e. Sun.

The epithet of Sun is given to important gods like Yama, Varuna and Indra etc. For example Indra is compared with Sun at many places in RigVeda but in the hymn RV.1.131(1) he is called Asura of this world (Indraya hi dhyo Asura). Asura as Sun is also described in the hymn RV.1.35 (7) " vi suparno antrikshanya akhyad gabhir vepa Asurah sunithah" (there at the horizon speaking with serious quiver/vibration Sun with golden wings (suparno Ashura) gives good guidance).

There was a cult of Sun worshiping before the emergence of 'fire cult' and followers of earlier cult were called as Asura. This distinction can be seen in RigVeda itself in the hymn RV.1.123(3) "devo no atra Savita damuna anagaso vochati Surya" (our god here is Savita (Sun) in villages Nagas  call it Surya).

There was some historical development which changed the meaning of Asura in the later scripture. However the traces of brilliant craftmanship of Asura we find even in Mahabharata e.g. Mayasur.

Comment: Yeah but I want to know what is the meaning of the word Asura?

Comment: Didn't I explain the meaning is Sun.

Comment: I like the etymology that asura could also mean sun in the vedas,so I upvoted the answer.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda So, truth is what we collectively "like?"

Comment: Having said that, Surya comes from PIE "súHr̥," so this is a line of reasoning worth investigation. Particularly interesting as (a-)/(an-) would mean "not __."

Answer (score 4):

There is no universally accepted answer to your question. However, because knowing how something came to be can help us better understand that thing, here's the etymology (history & origin) of the word.

### Etymology of Ásura

According to Wiktionary it's,

> From Proto-Indo-Aryan * *Hásuras*, from Proto-Indo-Iranian * *Hásuras*, from
>   Proto-Indo-European * *h₂ń̥suros*.
>
> Related to असु (*asu-*), with several possible etymologies and meanings.
>   In the context of *asura* conventionally associated with *asu-* in the
>   sense of **"master of the house"**. This meaning is not further narrowed
>   by its etymology: cf. Avestan ‎ (*ahu*, “lord”) and ‎
>   (*ahura*, “lord”), Hittite  (*ḥaššū*, “king”), and Latin *erus* (“lord”).
>   **Possibly ultimately from** Proto-Indo-European *h₂ens-* (**“to engender,
>   beget”**). Compare Old Norse *æsir*.
>
> T**he Brahmanas and the Puranas derive *asura* from another *asu-*,
>   "breath"**, a cognate of which is found in Av. *ahu-*, "life, existence".
>   In yet other post-Vedic Sanskrit literature, *asura* was back-formed as
>   *a-sura*, "non-sura", with *sura* then associated with a group of gods who
>   inhabit Indra's domain.

According to Etymonline,

> "spirit, lord," from Indo-Iranian *asuras*, from suffixed form of **PIE root *ansu-* "spirit"**

---

Interestingly, the origins and background meaning of *deva* clearly comes from "to shine," and is heavily connected to "the solar sky," that which provides life on Earth—whereas *ásura* (most likely) comes from the context of "breath," "lifeforce," "spirit." That is to say, the earliest difference in meaning was "that which provides the conditions in which one may exist" (deva) and **"that existence itself"** (ásura).

Comment: This is a context-based version of my previous post, which was too much pure data

Answer (score 2):

The basic meaning of Sura is from Saur/Surya i.e. one who radiates with light, just like a sun and knows his real self, Aatma(which is without Tamas). Hence, Gods in Hinduism are always depicted with a Sun like halo behind their heads. Asura is the opposite, one who does not know the Aatma and hence full of Tamas. Difference between Asuric and Sura buddhi has been discussed number of times in Vedas.

From [Chandogya Upanishad](https://upanishads.org.in/stories/the-story-of-indra-and-virochana), Chapter 8.7-12

> **The Story of Indra and Virochana**
>
> Once Prajapati, the creator of the universe announced, “The Self is
>   the sinless, ageless and deathless One; it has no sorrow nor hunger
>   nor thirst. The goal of all its desire is the Truth, Truth is the one
>   thing worthy of its resolve. It is this Self that has to be sought
>   after, it alone one should seek to know. And one who seeks after the
>   Self and knows it, gains possessions of all the worlds, wins all that
>   is desirable.” Both the gods and the demons heard this announcement
>   and thought, “We must know this Atman or Self and seek this knowledge
>   that promises all worlds.” Hence, Indra, the king of the gods and
>   Virochana, the leader of the demons, approached Prajapati with all the
>   humility of a disciple and requested him to impart this knowledge to
>   them. Prajapati accepted them as his disciples and asked them to stay
>   with him for thirty-two years. Both, Indra and Virochana, stayed on
>   living the life of a Brahmachari.  At the end of that period,
>   Prajapati called both of them and said, “Dear ones, the person visible
>   in the pupil of the eye is Atman.  This Atman is the Brahman, the
>   immortal and fearless.  Go and see yourself in a pan of water and then
>   tell me what you saw.” Next day when Prajapati asked both of them to
>   narrate their experience they both said, “Lord, we saw the Self
>   entirely as we are, the very image even to the very hairs and nails.”
>   “Go and adorn yourself and then look into the pan of water and tell me
>   about your experience” said Prajapati to both of them. Happy, they
>   went and adorned themselves, looked into the pan of water, came back
>   and replied to Prajapati, “Revered Sir, we saw ourselves well dressed,
>   well groomed and well adorned.” “Very good, this is Atman, the
>   immortal and fearless, the Brahman” thus confirmed Prajapati to them.
>   Both Indra and Virochana, went happy and very much satisfied in their
>   heart. Prajapati saw them going away and exclaimed to himself,
>   “Whether they are gods or demons they will inevitably perish if they
>   are satisfied with the mere reflection of the Reality.” **Virochana went
>   to the demons and taught them this knowledge by saying that this
>   bodily self is all that we need to know and serve and glorify. This is
>   the supreme knowledge by which one obtains the world here and
>   hereafter.** Indra was different from Virochana.  He realized that
>   something is wrong with what he has just learnt about the Atman. He
>   felt uneasy. He thought to himself that as the water reflects a well
>   adorned body so does it reflects a blind man if he is blind, a
>   defective man if he is defective. If a body is destroyed or dead, then
>   there is no reflection of a living body. How then could the body or
>   its reflection be said to be the deathless Atman? He went back to
>   Prajapati and said, “Lord, I see really nothing worthy in this body or
>   in its reflection. Please give me the true knowledge about the Atman.”
>   Prajapati was happy with Indra and asked Indra to stay with him for
>   another thirty-two years. At the end of that period Prajapati called
>   him and said, “That which moves about in dreams is Atman.” Indra
>   seemed to be satisfied and made his way to the abode of gods. But as
>   he went along, again doubt crept into his mind and he thought, “How
>   can the dream self be Atman? In dreams one suffers, one is wounded,
>   one weeps when afflicted. The fearless and sinless Atman cannot be
>   subject to such happenings. This does not seem to be the truth. Even
>   this time also something again is wrong with what I have learnt.” He
>   came back and prostrated himself before Prajapati requesting him to
>   explain the truth of Atman. As usual, Prajapati told him to stay with
>   him for another period of thirty-two years.  Indra was all prepared.
>   At the end of this period, Prajapati called Indra and said: “The self
>   who is full pleased and is in a happy mood in deep sleep is the
>   Atman.” Indra was satisfied and went home. But before he reached his
>   place, again doubt overwhelmed him and he said to himself, “In a
>   dreamless sleep, the self does not know itself. It is not conscious of
>   its own existence. How then can the unconscious self be Atman when it
>   is described as the ever luminous one, ever conscious one?” He came
>   back again to Prajapati and reported to him about his difficulties.
>   This time Prajapati was more pleased with Indra and told him to spend
>   five more years with him. After the period was over Prajapati called
>   Indra beside him and said: “O Indra, you have deserved the knowledge
>   of the highest truth by your persistent effort and intense
>   inquisitiveness.” Saying this Prajapati revealed that part of the
>   highest knowledge to Indra for which he was ready at that point of
>   time. “This body is subject to death yet it embodies the deathless and
>   bodiless Atman. This embodied Self falls into the trap of all
>   dualities like pleasure and pain, but the bodiless Atman is not
>   touched by any duality. So long as the Atman resides in the body and
>   attaches itself to them he seems limited and restricted, but again
>   when freed from the body becomes one with the infinite spirit. When
>   the Atman leaves the body, goes wandering freely in the infinite
>   worlds. The eye, the ear, the senses, the mind are there only in order
>   that the Atman may see and hear and think. It is on account of Atman
>   and in the Atman that the things and beings exist. He is the Truth and
>   the final repository of all existence.” This time when Indra went back
>   to impart this knowledge to the gods, he had no doubt. The gods
>   received the true knowledge and therefore live in the full knowledge
>   of their Self. **And because Virochana was satisfied with the knowledge
>   of body as self, the Asura demons, even today live in the ignorance taking
>   body as Self.**

This is also discussed in [Bhagwat Geeta](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/16), where "Asura" has been translated as demon in english, but the real meaning of word "Asura" is the one in whom Tamas dominates and devoid of knowledge of Self-soul, Satva and considers manifested reality is the only truth just like animals.

> BG 16.1 – 16.3 The Supreme Divine Personality said: O scion of Bharat,
>   these are the saintly virtues of those endowed with a divine
>   nature—fearlessness, purity of mind, steadfastness in spiritual
>   knowledge, charity, control of the senses, performance of sacrifice,
>   study of the sacred books, austerity, and straightforwardness;
>   non-violence, truthfulness, absence of anger, renunciation,
>   peacefulness, restraint from fault-finding, compassion toward all
>   living beings, absence of covetousness, gentleness, modesty, and lack
>   of fickleness; vigor, forgiveness, fortitude, cleanliness, bearing
>   enmity toward none, and absence of vanity.
>
> BG 16.4 O Parth, the qualities of those who possess a demoniac nature
>   are hypocrisy, arrogance, conceit, anger, harshness, and ignorance.
>
> BG 16.5 The divine qualities lead to liberation, while the demoniac
>   qualities are the cause for a continuing destiny of bondage. Grieve
>   not, O Arjun, as you were born with saintly virtues.
>
> BG 16.6 There are two kinds of beings in this world—those endowed with
>   a divine nature and those possessing a demoniac nature. I have
>   described the divine qualities in detail, O Arjun. Now hear from me
>   about the demoniac nature. Bhagavad Gita 16.7
>
> Those possessing a demoniac nature do not comprehend what actions are
>   proper and what are improper. Hence, they possess neither purity, nor
>   good conduct, nor even truthfulness.
>
> BG 16.8 **They say, “The world is without absolute truth, without any
>   basis (for moral order), and without a God (who has created or is
>   controlling it). It is created from the combination of the two sexes,
>   and has no purpose other than sexual gratification.”**
>
> BG 16.9 Holding fast to such views, these misdirected souls, with
>   small intellect and cruel actions, arise as enemies of the world
>   threatening its destruction.
>
> BG 16.10 Harboring insatiable lust, full of hypocrisy, pride and
>   arrogance, the demoniac cling to their false tenets. Thus illusioned,
>   they are attracted to the impermanent and work with impure resolve.
>
> BG 16.11 They are obsessed with endless anxieties that end only with
>   death. Still, they maintain with complete assurance that gratification
>   of desires and accumulation of wealth is the highest purpose of life.
>
> BG 16.12 Held in bondage by hundreds of desires, and driven by lust
>   and anger, they strive to accumulate wealth by unjust means, all for
>   the gratification of their senses.
>
> BG 16.13 – 16.15 The demoniac persons think, “I have gained so much
>   wealth today, and I shall now fulfill this desire of mine. This is
>   mine, and tomorrow I shall have even more. That enemy has been
>   destroyed by me, and I shall destroy the others too! I am like God
>   himself, I am the enjoyer, I am powerful, and I am happy. I am wealthy
>   and I have highly placed relatives. Who else is equal to me? I shall
>   perform sacrifices (to the celestial gods); I shall give alms; I shall
>   rejoice.” In this way, they are deluded by ignorance.
>
> BG 16.16 **Possessed and led astray by such imaginings, enveloped in a
>   mesh of delusion, and addicted to the gratification of sensuous
>   pleasures, they descend to the murkiest hell.**

Comment: question is about vedas .. please make sure to give vedic references only.... thanks