# How does the word 'Agni' acquire its traditional meaning as fire?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, agni, words

Literally, अग्नि = अंग् + नि, नलोपश्च।
And the root verb अंग् means "to revolve". The meaning of the suffix नि , I couldn't find anywhere, and then suddenly we start associating अग्नि with the sacrificial fire. Is it somewhat biased by tradition/convention? Maybe the meaning of the suffix has to do something here. Otherwise at certain instances in the Vedas, the meaning of verse gets too awful ( like in Rv. 2|1|1, Vaj. 11|27, त्वमग्ने ... द्भ्यः ... जायसे शुचिः। Agni being born of water - somewhat contradictory.)

Pardon me, but what I am actually asking is the "how-to" of assigning meanings to sounds/dhatus/pratyayas in sanskrit, which was perhaps known to the niruktakars at Yask's time, but now is (maybe, maybe not) lost.

Comment: Hope it doesn't get flagged for Sanskrit question.

Answer (score 2):

Sanskrit words have a lot of meanings. For example [asura](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22135/19001) means both good and bad. The etymology of *agni* is given in Nirukta 7:14.

[image]

> He indeed takes the letter *a* from root *I* (to go), the letter *g* from *akj* (to shine), or *dah* (to burn) with the root *no* as the last member.

Comment: Could you pls verbatim write it out? Image is not clear enough to read. Thank you.